# How to pass a block to assert_raise in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Using ruby-1.9.3...

I've read some of the canonical blog posts on the subject of blocks & Procs, but I don't see why these two situations are different:

```
module TestHelpers
  def bad_arg_helper(&scenario)

    # this works fine, test passes (without the next line)
    assert_raise ArgumentError, "wrong type of arguments, pass Fixnum or Range parameters", { Myclass.myfunc "bad" }

    # even though the exception is correctly raised in myfunc, this assert does not see it and the test fails
    assert_raise ArgumentError, "wrong type of arguments, pass Fixnum or Range parameters", scenario.call
  end
end

class TestClass < Test::Unit::TestCase
  include TestHelpers

  def test_bad_args
    bad_arg_helper { Myclass.myfunc "bad" }
  end
end
```

How do you pass a block to a test helper in another module?

Comment: Try `&scenario` instead of `scenario.call` in the second line.

Comment: That did it...  I have not seen an example where the `&` is used outside of the parameter list.  Why does `method.call` not work here?  When is it appropriate to use the `&` in the method body?  Please feel free to answer for credit, and thanks in any case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the three variants in the code:

```
require 'test/unit'
class Myclass
  def self.myfunc(par)
    raise ArgumentError unless par.is_a?(Fixnum)
  end
end

module TestHelpers
  def bad_arg_helper(&scenario)

    # this works fine, test passes (without the next line)
    assert_raise( ArgumentError, "wrong type of arguments, pass Fixnum or Range parameters") { Myclass.myfunc "bad" }

    # even though the exception is correctly raised in myfunc, this assert does not see it and the test fails
    assert_raise( ArgumentError, "wrong type of arguments, pass Fixnum or Range parameters", &scenario)
    assert_raise( ArgumentError, "wrong type of arguments, pass Fixnum or Range parameters") { yield }
    assert_raise( ArgumentError, "wrong type of arguments, pass Fixnum or Range parameters") { scenario.call }
  end
end

class TestClass < Test::Unit::TestCase
  include TestHelpers

  def test_bad_args
    bad_arg_helper { Myclass.myfunc "bad" }
  end
end
```

Comment: Great examples.  If I understand the semantics correctly, a reference to a Proc (`&scenario`) can be passed into a function like any other variable (ie. inside the parentheses), but an actual block cannot.  I don't see why `scenario.call` works inside of the curly braces, though.  Does it return the return value of the block?

Comment: `scenario.call` calls `scenario` and the result is passed to the method. So without the curly braces, you don't return a block, but the result of scenario. With the curly braces you pass a block to the method. inside the Block, you call `scenario`. One problem is the double meaning of the curly braces: It can be a Hash or a Block. Without the round braces, ruby has problems to identify, if you have a hash or a block.